# logic AND function on array with arbitrary/variable N values

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, logic

I am stuck with a huge problem. I have a dynamic array that may contain anything between 0 and N values (for simplicity of the question, assume they are all boolean e.g. 0 or 1). Of course, once an array is defined/read, the number of values is not unknown anymore. And, I can exclude two trivial cases easily at the start: 0 (empty) and single value array.

What is left is the case of 2+ values inside an array and a need to perform logical AND operation on all of them.

For example:

```
$array = array
(
    $a,
    $b,
    $c,
    .
    .
    .
    $n
);

    $logical_function = $a && $b && $c && ... && $n;
```

Is this even possible to do somehow in PHP? I know how to generate dynamic / variable variables names from an array, but how do I write the AND part function?

Thanks

Comment: any reason you can't just use a foreach loop? For AND - as soon as you find the first 0 you can quit because the complete expression won't be true. For OR - as soon as you find the first 1 you can quit because you know the complete expression is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
function logicalAnd(array $arr) 
{
    $result = true;
    foreach($arr as $element) 
    {
        $result = $result && $element;
        if (!$result) { return false; }
    }
    return $result
}
```

Comment: Hi mkasberg, will test this and report. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I just added `if (!$result) { return false; }`, which is an optimization that will save time with larger arrays (if they evaluate to false).

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed - it is so simple and elegant, I can't beleive got stuck on this one :)

Answer (score 1):

If just one of the array element is `false`, the result will be false. So you can skip inspecting other elements when facing one `false`:

```
$result = true;
foreach($array as $arr)
{
    if($arr)
      $result = true;
    else
    {
      $result = false;
      break;
    }
}
return $result;
```

Comment: You can't start with `$result = false;`. `false && anything` is false.

Comment: Thanks hamed, too. Yes, this can greatly improve execution speed.